# Copy Protection and Trial Creation for OSX Applications - Suggestions Please?

Tags: macos, copy-protection, trial, trialware

Silicon Realms (Digital River - Armadillo) used to have a Mac application protection/trial builder. They discontinued it this year most likely due to Mac App store not allowing 3rd party protection mechanisms or trials. Does anybody know of alternatives for creating trials and generally wrapping apps for copy protection which **will not** be sold on the app store? I am not expecting iron clad solutions... just simple copy deterrents and 30 day trial mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is [ExeShield](http://www.exeshield.com/compareMac.htm).  No idea how well it works, but since I just discovered that Silicon Realms discontinued their program I'll probably have to go with that.

Apple is working harder and harder to get you into their store - and take their 30% of the gross off the top.  Eventually Apple will do anything, legal or no, to make sure that they make more money out of your program than you do...